# Calculating Avg, Max, and Min using a .txt input file with both integers and strings mixed

Tags: java, io, max, average, min

Please help. I've looked everywhere and am stumped on how to finish this program. I need to calculate the average, max, and min from a data input file. They need to look like this:

```
System.out.println("The average total score of the class is: " + total/27);
System.out.println(maxName + "got the maximum score of: " + maxVal);
System.out.println(minName + "got the maximum score of: " + minVal);
```

For the average I don't know why the while loop in my main isn't working. It calculates a value of zero. I also don't know how I can make it so the 27 isn't hard coded. For the max and min values, I have no clue about those. i don't even have a guess. A lot of things I've looked at for these use ways we haven't been taught (like a buffered something for instance, or using the Collections class which we haven't learned about that either. I just need a basic way of accomplishing these. I will include everything I have so far. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Input File:

```
9
Andy Borders
200
250
400
John Smith
120
220
330
Alvin Smith
225
300
278
Mike Borell
250
250
500
Jim Jones
325
325
155
Robert Fennel
200
150
350
Craig Fenner
230
220
480
Bill Johnson
120
150
220
Brent Garland
220
240
350
```

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Project5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        String SnumStudents = inputFile.nextLine();
        int numStudents = Integer.parseInt(SnumStudents);
        Student [] studentList = new Student[numStudents];
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            String line = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score1 = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score2 = inputFile.nextLine();
            String score3 = inputFile.nextLine();
            studentList [i] = new Student(line, Integer.parseInt(score1), Integer.parseInt(score2), Integer.parseInt(score3));
        }
        System.out.println("Name\t\tScore1\tScore2\tScore3\tTotal");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        for (int i=0; i< studentList.length;i++){
            System.out.println(studentList[i].getName() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore1() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore2() + "\t" + studentList[i].getScore3() + "\t" + studentList[i].getTotal());
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("The total number of students in this class is: " + studentList.length);
        int total = 0;
        while (inputFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            int value = inputFile.nextInt();
            total = total + value;
        }
        System.out.println("The average total score of the class is: " + total/27);
        System.out.println(maxName + "got the maximum score of: " + maxVal);
        System.out.println(minName + "got the maximum score of: " + minVal);
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading from " + fileName);
    }
    finally {
    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private int score1;
private int score2;
private int score3;
private int total;
private double average;

public Student(String n, int s1, int s2, int s3){
    name = n;
    score1 = s1;
    score2 = s2;
    score3 = s3;
    total = s1 + s2 + s3;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public int getScore1(){
    return score1;
}
public int getScore2(){
    return score2;
}
public int getScore3(){
    return score3;
}
public int getTotal(){
    return total;
}
public double computeAverage(){
    return average;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is never getting executed.  By the time you finish reading lines of the file in your for loop, there are no more lines of the file to consume.  So, `inputFile.hasNextInt()` is never true.

The 27 is hard-coded because of the line

```
System.out.println("The average total score of the class is: " + total/27);
```

You need to change the 27 here to some variable that will represent the total number of scores.

You are storing all of the scores for each person.  To find the min (max) you just need to go through each of the values and find the smallest (largest) one and store them.

Comment: Everything you say makes sense, but doesn't help much because I don't know how the syntax even looks for doing these things.